# My Kali Linux virtual Box says it's connected through wired connection but is unable to connect to internet

Tags: linux, kali-linux

Earlier today I was able to connect to the internet through wired connection on my virtual box, but when I closed the virtual box to edit some settings and came back, I was unable to access the internet. I am very very new to Kali.

Answer (score 0):

The `ifconfig` command in Linux will give you some information about what your networking interfaces are doing, i.e. ethernet card, wireless card, etc.

To restart your networking, try this command: `service network-manager restart`

Maybe I should have started by asking *what settings did you change?*

Comment: I changed the amount of processors being used from 2 to 4 because it was acting slow

Comment: Did you try the above commands? What are your network settings in VirtualBox?

Comment: I tried the commands but it still doesn't work

Comment: What is the output of `ifconfig` . Also, have you tried just a reboot of the VM? It's hard to troubleshoot with limited information. We don't know your network adapter configuration or what you have done to try to fix this. Please provide as much info as you can.

Comment: I have tried rebooting the VM multiple times.What do you want from the output of the `ifconfig` specifically. Sorry I'm new.

Comment: 1. Provide the network settings of your VM. 2. Provide ALL of the output from ifconfig. This will give us a start.